# Running Separate Docker Applications on Different Ports, one as Subdomain

Tags: proxy, ssl, docker, nginx, certbot

I've rebuilt my personal website as a Dockerized chain as well as a colleagues' web app. Both projects are built using containers are displaying on two separate ports, one on port 80 and one on port 2019. Each are running separate Certbot containers to keep SSL encryption. I'm not running Nginx as part of the host yet, I'm just mapping ports on the host to the Nginx containers running each app.

What I want is to have say, `example.com` be my personal website that shows what is being displayed on port 80, and have `application.example.com` be the proxy to the web app. For context, each Docker chain is a Django project using independent chains of PostgreSQL, Certbot, and Nginx to handle databases, SSL, and hosting respectively.

Would I need to setup Nginx on the host to handle the routing? If so, how could I do that and keep the SSL protections for each application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would I need to setup Nginx on the host to handle the routing?

Sounds like you want all domains to work with the same standard HTTP(S) port. In that case, yes, you'll want a central Nginx (or Apache, or HAproxy) instance that acts as a "reverse proxy". (It's easiest to put it on the host, but it could be its own container.)

- "Central" nginx listens on ports 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS
- Users visit `https://foo.example.com` without specifying a custom port, and connect to the "central" nginx instance
- Nginx connects to the apropriate Docker container's address:port according to its `proxy_pass` configuration:

  ```
  server {
      server_name foo.example.com;
      listen ...;
      ssl_certificate ...;
      location / { proxy_pass http://<docker_ip>:2019; }
  }

  server {
      server_name bar.example.com;
      listen ...;
      ssl_certificate ...;
      location / { proxy_pass ...; }
  }
  ```

On the other hand, if you specifically want the custom ports to be present in URLs (e.g. `https://sub.example.com:2019`), then no HTTP proxy is necessary – just TCP-level "port forwarding" via iptables, and the different domain names do not affect anything at all.

> how could I do that and keep the SSL protections for each application?

In this case, TLS is hop-by-hop, i.e. client→reverseproxy and reverseproxy→webserver are two separate TLS connections. Certbot is needed for the first, since it goes over the Internet. (The second however is internal to your system and doesn't need TLS much.)

In other words, you'd have to move the Certbot certificates to the "central" nginx instance. There are two ways you can configure this:

1. Nginx proxies all requests to Docker containers. The containers run their own Certbot instances, and after each renewal they somehow copy the new certificate+key to the host system so that the "central" Nginx could use it.
2. Nginx proxies all requests *except* `/.well-known/acme-challenge/`. Only the "central" Nginx system runs Certbot and handles renewal for all domains. The containers don't run Certbot; they either don't use TLS at all, or use a self-issued certificate.

---

Although that said, it is possible to have end-to-end TLS, with the host routing connections entirely based on the TLS 'Server Name Indication' field. HAproxy and sniproxy can be used for this, instead of Nginx.

Comment: I can get behind using Nginx as a reverse proxy for the host. 
My first question would be if I need to dismantle the Certbot containers to have the "central" Nginx instance using its own Certbot, since as you said the client -> reverseproxy is over the internet and what happens in the Docker chain is mostly independent. 
My second question is how would I set this up? I've set up static sites with server blocks with Nginx before, but this would be moreso wrapping a port as a proxy, right? So would this server block layout need the same SSL certificates for both apps?

Comment: Each domain would have its own server block and its own certificate, exactly the same as with multiple normal domains/vhosts. The only difference is instead of specifying a document root you use [proxy_pass](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) to specify the "forwarding" URL. In fact, if you've used nginx+fastcgi or nginx+uwsgi earlier, there's very little difference between proxying to an uwsgi app and proxying to another http webserver living in a docker.

Comment: As for Certbot, that should have been answered by the 2nd section already. (If you choose option 2 with central Certbot, it can be either two certs or one multidomain cert, it doesn't matter.)

Comment: In making the Certbot containers, they use the certifications on the host itself, so it does in fact follow the second section. That's my misunderstanding.

I think I can figure out how to do the proxy_pass as you mentioned. I'll update if I have an issue with it.

Comment: Update: I've done what you said and have the Chains share the SSL certificate with the Host, therefore having a central certificate. I then was able to have my personal website proxy_pass to that respective chain. I was also able to get the `application.example.com` to appear and route to the correct app, however, Chrome will not recognize the SSL certificate on the subdomain. I've tried this with another Docker chain and experienced the same result. Do I need to have Certbot create certificates for each subdomain? Or would it just be easier to have a separate URL point to the Host?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a separate URL". When using a reverse proxy setup like this, you're _always_ meant to connect to the host, and certificates are only taken from the host's configuration (hence the recommendation to have Certbot on the host). The only thing connecting to your Docker webapps should be the proxy itself – not a web browser directly.

Comment: I read what I wrote and figured out the issue. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It's most likely worth to mention that both Nginx "servers" can listen on the same port (e.g. `listen 443 ssl` could be set instead of `listen ...` in the example of the answer in both the server blocks) for a single Nginx service (process with its own workers/threads), and in turn, Nginx would determine the corresponding route based on the `server_name` while listening on the same port. Thank you! ^^